# Como puedo subir el map.py al app.py usando html y python?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando subir mi juego al local host 5002, pero tras la bienvenida del usuario que se acaba de conectar, no puedo subir las ademas escenas y elecciones que tienen que hacer.

tengo esto:

```
from flask import Flask, session, request
from flask import url_for, redirect, render_template
import map

app = Flask(__name__) #se need como parametro

@app.route('/', methods = ["POST"])
def login():
    user = request.form.get('name')
    return render_template("index.html", name = user)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def hello():
    return render_template("form.html")

@app.route ('/', methods = ["POST"])
def game():
    session['scene'] = map.START.urlname
    return redirect(url_for('game_get'))
@app.route('/game', methods=['POST'])
def game_get():
thescene = map.SCENES[session['scene']]
return render_template('next_scene.html', scene=thescene)
```

y este es el map.py con la descripcion de las escenas, las opciones y el .urlname :

```
class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self, title, urlname, description):
        self.title = title
        self.urlname = urlname
        self.description = description
        self.paths = {}

    def go(self, direction):
        default_direction = None
        if '*' in self.paths.keys():
            default_direction = self.paths.get('*')
        return self.paths.get(direction, default_direction)

    def add_paths(self, paths):
        self.paths.update(paths)


first_start = Scene("Alley", "first_start",
"""
Now, be very careful. You're a thief that just robbed a bank.
You're trapped in a dead-end-road that has an apple tree.
There are only two exits, at both ends of the street below you.
To the right, there's a rabid dog that would follow anything thatmoves.
To the left, a cop.
How do you elude the dangers and flee alive?
"""
)
```

y las opciones para cada escena en el botón de "aceptar"

```
SCENES = {
first_start.urlname : first_start,
etc with the other scenes
}
```

pero como he dicho, tras que me salga el ("Hello A!") e imprima la primera escena de mi mapa en el /game con el botón de "aceptar", al incluir algo y clicar, no me lleva a la siguiente escena ni muestra el mensaje de "error de input, no es una opción" ni el "Has muerto!".
Solo aparece el Error: 
 Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

¿Alguna idea de como arreglar esto??